# Alternative to layers of if statements

Tags: if-statement, lisp, boolean, conditional-statements

Sometimes I end up with layers of if statements in my lisp code. Is there any alternative to doing this?

Answer (score 4):

It's one of those cases where the answer, unfortunately, is "it depends". In some cases, the obvious choice is to use `cond`.

```
(if condition1
   result1
   (if condition2
       result2
       default))

;; naturally converted to:
(cond (condition1 result1)
      (condition2 result2)
      (t default))
```

At other times, `cond` paired with a bit of `or` or `and` may be exactly what you want.

```
(if condition1
   (if condition2
       result12
       result1)
   (if condition2
       result2
       default))

;; naturally turns intoteh answe
(cond ((and condition1 condition2) result12)
      (condition1 result1)
      (condition2 result2)
      (t default))
```

NB, I have only written, not tested, this code, but in principle it should be fine.

Unfortunately, there are probably times where even the somewhat simpler-to-read `cond` form isn't clear enough and in those cases it's usually worth staring at the actual problem a bit harder. There may be a way of decomposing the logic in a better way (dispatch table, outer logic calling functions with suitable parameters, ...).

Answer (score 2):

There are few directions you can move in to change your code.

1. Creating higher order functions that encapsulate conditions, or, perhaps, macros, or, maybe reusing existing macros (take a look [at case macro](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_case_.htm) for example). `remove-if` would be an example of a high-order function that can spare you writing an "if".
2. Use polymorphism. Lisp has classes, objects, overloads and all the instrumentation you would expect an object system to have (perhaps even a little extra ;).

Suppose you have this code:

```
;; Suppose your `person' is a list that has that person's
;; name as its first element:

(defun hello! (person)
  (if (string= (car person) "John")
        (concatenate 'string "Hello, " (car person))
     (print "Hello, who are you?")))

(defun goodbye! (person)
  (if (string= (car person) "John")
        (concatenate 'string "Goodbye, " (car person))
     (print "Goodbye, mysterious stranger!")))

;; You would use it like so:
(hello! '("John" x y z))
(goodbye! '(nil x y z))
```

Now, you could rewrite it as:

```
(defclass person () ())

(defclass friend (person)
  ((name :accessor name-of
         :initarg :name)))

(defgeneric hello! (person))
(defgeneric goodbye! (person))

(defmethod hello! ((person person))
  (print "Hello, who are you?"))

(defmethod hello! ((person friend))
  (print (concatenate 'string "Hello, " (name-of person))))

(defmethod goodbye! ((person person))
  (print "Goodbye, mysterious stranger!"))

(defmethod goodbye! ((person friend))
  (print (concatenate 'string "Goodbye, " (name-of person))))

;; Which you would use like so:

(hello! (make-instance 'person))
(goodbye! (make-instance 'friend :name "John"))

;; Note that however the later is significantly more verbose
;; the ratio will change when you have more `if's which you
;; can systematize as objects, or states.
```

In other words, by encapsulating the state you can avoid explicitly writing condition statements. You would also gain some readability on the way, as you wouldn't need to memorize which piece of the list contains what info - you  would now have it labelled "name".

Comment: Thank you, although somewhat abstract, this seems to be very powerful. I'll take time to digest and apply this.